# Impersonating IUSR from code

Tags: asp.net, iis, impersonation

In IIS Manager, in `Authentication` - `Anonymous Authentication` I have `Anonymous user identity` set as `IUSR`.

Now if If put this into web.config:

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

then `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returns `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`.

but if I remove

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

how can I impersonate the `IUSR` from code? I tried to use [`SimpleImpersonation`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleImpersonation/) to do it but then I need the password of `IUSR`. I found a way to get it using obsolete `adsutil.vbs` but I don't have it on Windows 8.1 / IIS 8.5.

This question is theoretical, I don't have a need for impersonating `IUSR` but I find the fact that IIS does it interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUSR is built-in now and does not have a password ([more info](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis)).
IIS as a service has rights to obtain IUSR impersonation token -- check example on [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx).
There is IIS API that provides token handle, which ASP.NET runtime uses.
I believe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) may be relevant code from reference sources.

As for actual question, I don't know how anyone can legally impersonate IUSR, sorry.